# Unity: Editing a DontDestroyOnLoad object in another scene

Tags: unity

I figured out how to make certain objects like my Camera and Canvas persist across scenes, but I can't figure out how to access them in the editor from scenes in which they're not instantiated.

I can make these objects prefabs and make my changes to the prefab rather than the instance, but then I can't make references in the prefab to objects in the hierarchy; I would have to use an instance of a prefab to do that.

How can I edit subsequent scenes in the same way that I edited the first scene, where all the DontDestroyOnLoad objects are instantiated for the first time and I can access them through the hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I figured out how to make certain objects like my Camera and Canvas
>   persist across scenes, but I can't figure out how to access them in
>   the editor from scenes in which they're not instantiated.

A scene is basically a **collection of objects** (and **serialized properties**) that the engine bundles and can load together. As such, **it's allowed to cross reference objects that belong to the same scene**.

[DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) mark an object in such a way that when a non additive scene loading operation([Apllication.LoadLevel](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html)|[LoadLevelAsync](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevelAsync.html)) is performed, that object won't be destroyed. It controls the **runtime lifetime of an object**. In editor mode, isn't possible to reference an object across different scenes.

> I can make these objects prefabs and make my changes to the prefab
>   rather than the instance, but then I can't make references in the
>   prefab to objects in the hierarchy; I would have to use an instance of
>   a prefab to do that.

That's how it works, right. If you want to setup references in one of your persistent object you basically have 2 ways:

1. **Instantiate** (or save it into a scene) **once**, prevent it gets destroyed([DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)), and initialize reference at runtime when a different level is loaded (es. [OnLevelWasLoaded](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnLevelWasLoaded.html))
2. **Save a prefab instance** of such objects **in each scene**, and serialize references you need into the relative instances.

> How can I edit subsequent scenes in the same way that I edited the
>   first scene, where all the DontDestroyOnLoad objects are instantiated
>   for the first time and I can access them through the hierarchy?

If you are asking how to reference in a `Scene_B` a prefab is supposed to be instantiated and not destroyed in a `Scene_A`, in `editor mode` then **you can't.**
The object instance is only available when a particular scene will be loaded (at runtime or in the editor for editing)

Comment: There may be a method, using custom editor scripts, where a specified set of objects are spawned when a scene is loaded in editor, and any changes to them saved out to the corresponding prefabs. I don't have a pre-made solution of this type to point to just yet though. You're right that, without extending the editor functionality, this is not available out of the box.

Comment: There are way to detect if a scene is changed/loaded in the editor, but still not possible in anyway cross reference objects across different scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the new SceneManagerAdditiveLoading function. [You can view a tutorial at YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9h_iu4Zx5I&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: I think using additive scene loading is a good direction for solving this problem. Fleshing this out to a complete example (without relying on an external video) would make this answer even better.

Answer (score -1):

So you have:

- Scene one that contains the camera and canvas (which have been marked don't destroy on load). It also has a script that does a load for scene two.
- Scene two that contains objects that need to reference the canvas in scene one.

There's a few solutions for this:

**Solution one (low effort)**

Use GameObject.Find in Scene two to find the relevant objects in scene one, and assign them to your scripts.

**Solution two**

Create a singleton manager, which will avoid the sometimes expensive GameObject.Find call. A script in scene two can reference variables mediated by the singleton.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var GameObject object=GameObject.Find("object name that won't be destroyed");
```

You will get an object reference in each scene.

Comment: This will work once the object has been instantiated, but it *will not* work straight from  the editor in an alternate scene, as this question asks.